# Maybe Failed Ikea Aventurin Ceiling Lamp

Tags: lamp

I have an Ikea Aventurin ceiling lamp that has stopped working.  I opened up the lamp itself and discovered it has a 8 amp fuse inside.  The fuse looks fine but I'd like to replace it as a first step in troubleshooting the fixture. Is this the correct fuse? Fast-Blow Fuse 8A 8amp 125V Glass Fuses? Thanks!

[image: Aventurin Lamp]

Comment: not Fast blow, use slow blow.

Comment: Fuse looks fine, why not test it before replacing.  If not the fuse, you take down the light, replace the fuse, put light back up and it does not work, repeat.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good idea rather than spending money on fuses to replace a still good one. Will consult youtube for fuse testing procedure.

Comment: Any continuity tester  will check a fuse, it is good or bad, no in between.